# What is currently the best way to ask the user on iOS and MacOS for saved credentials

Tags: ios, login, mac-os-x, apple

At first I am an Android user so please forgive me when this is very oblivious.

I am working on a Flutter plugin, which should make it as easy as possible to sign in into any Flutter app using my plugin. Therefore I need to go one step back and find out what is currently the best way to ask the user on iOS and MacOS for saved credentials?

I read in the past from [Shared Web Credentials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials), which seems still to exists but the API to query those credentials was deprecated with that quote: *"Use ASAuthorizationController to make an ASAuthorizationPasswordRequest instead."* which lead me to think that this way is some kind of legacy.

I found from [Ricky Mondello](https://twitter.com/rmondello/status/1487108265859330055) this screenshot:
[image]

Is this currently the way to go? Is there the same way for MacOS or is that limited to iOS?

Bonus question: Can you point me to the right part at the Apple documentation to implement it correctly?